# Getting envelope of noisy signal

Tags: python, time-domain, noise-cancellation, interference

I am analyzing some interferometry data and have a time signal that looks like this:

[image]

Our temporal resolution is unfortunately not enough to resolve the fringes.

I need to get the upper envelope of the signal to perform some analyses. I have tried everything (in Python) such as getting the Hilbert transform, using a low-pass filter, a Savitzky–Golay filter but no luck so far in getting something I can work with.

Any suggestions for dealing with the data would be very appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you described the limitations of the approaches you've tried so far.

Comment: With the Hilbert transform, its absolute value mostly behaves as the original signal, which does not help at all. With both of the filters, I am unable to smoothen the signal without having the processed data envelope completely losing its ressemblance to that of the original one.

Comment: Try something simple: e.g. absolute value followed by a low-pass filter. Then post the results and describe what you don't like about them

Comment: What Hilmar said and see this post for an example: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81944/envelope-detection-using-hilbert-transform/81945#81945

Comment: Thanks guys, both your comments helped me finally solve the problem.

Comment: Check out the information at: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/938.php

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235530/how-to-get-high-and-low-envelope-of-a-signal/).

Comment: It would help if you posted/pointed to the actual data.   Then what signal you expect and what the noise source is.