How to get a reliable envelope of a signal with clipped peaks?
I'm trying to compute the power per minute in the time domain of some seismic signals. I deal with signals sampled at 5 kHz characterized by random amplitude peaks emerging from low background noise or zero-amplitude time intervals. Before computing the square of the signal, some authors determine its envelope through the Hilbert transform "which compensates for the asymmetric offset of the raw seismic signal around the zero-amplitude level" (Nicollier et al., 2022).
In some circumstances my signals saturate (i.e. their peaks are clipped to the maximum values of 10 V), and I have found that in this case the envelope reaches quite high values, which are higher than the maximum value of the clipped peaks. Here attached two examples from two different pieces of the same seismic signal, with no saturation and saturation (raw signal + envelope).
Do you think it is necessary to determine the signal envelope before computing the signal power? If yes, what could I do in order to determine a reliable envelope of the signal? Is there a way to deal with clipped peaks?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Nicollier et al. (2022): https://doi.org/10.1029/2021EA001962

Could you please update your question to provide a clear definition as to what you mean by “envelope”? If you are looking to track the peaks with a certain attack and decay rate, the Hilbert Transform is not well suited for that purpose- so would be good to clarify what exactly you would like to do.

(see this other post that details this point I am trying to make in my prior comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81945/21048 )

@DanBoschen thank you for you reply, I have edited my question by adding some more details.

If the clipped portion contains critical data for your application, the clipping pretty much means «signal was 10V or more», but the exact information is lost. Various inpainting or model fitting cold provide better or worse guesses to what those samples should have been

Boosting a (nonclipped) signal by 2/3/10 times, clipping it at +/-10V, doing your envelope calculation, inverting the boost might give you an idea about the magnitude of the error for a given input amplitude

If the clipped peaks are infrequent enough, you could try deleting the few samples that have been clipped and try to determining the clipped and now deleted samples by extrapolating/interpolating a (band-limited) signal through the  the known unclipped sample values.
